# use css and jquery to create a "map" w/ hover effect (scrolls: up, right, bottom, left)

Tags: jquery, css

I want to be able to have the anchor links (Top, Top Right, Right, Bottom Right, Bottom, Bottom Left, Left, Top Left) on .hover or mouse enter, scroll to their respective locations. I need the anchor tags to be positioned absolutely so that they will never move when the actual map scrolls.

But anyways, that's the basic idea I'm trying to create.

> EDIT: Now that I think about it, using anchor tags might be going
>   about it wrong. The map will need to have a higher z-index value then
>   the anchor tags themselves because there will content on the map that needs to be clicked on. The way I have the fiddle right now would
>   actually be wrong.
>
> The functionality should be a gradual "ease" of movement. starting off
>   in from middle (move slow) and further up you get (move fast). I
>   imagine using mouseEnter and mouseLeav w/ page x and y coordinates
>   would be the answer., am I right on thinking that way in stead of
>   using the anchor tag method?

here is the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YWnzc/131/

Comment: Something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/YWnzc/128/

Comment: that is a great solution that works perfect for using anchor tags z-index'd on top of the map. I made a quick edit to the question because I realized that using anchor tags on top of the map would be a bad idea (because there will be content on the map that can be clicked), If i used the anchor tag method z-index'd on top, those anchor tags would be getting in the way of my content. Is there another method we can use such as "mouseEnter/mouseLeave" and "x and y" coordiates on the #viewport itself to achieve the same result?

Comment: Couldn't you use a series of divs or spans instead of links? Obviously I only did the top/bottom/left/right in the example but the other directions are trivial. If you want me to post this as an answer let me know. Actually now that I think about it, you could just use preventDefault on the links to stop their normal actions.

Comment: No, not quite yet. In essence, using a div or span would be the same as using the anchor tags because it would create a "block" of space on top of the map and it would get in the way of the content that will sit on top of the map. see this updated fiddle as an example of the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/YWnzc/131/ , The better way to do it seems to be making the js code interact with #viewport with x and y mouse positioning instead of using anchor tags, spans, or divs as our hooks (this is my guess).

Comment: What about divs (or spans) that had width and height but no inner content?

Comment: Sort of like http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/YWnzc/132/ (now all directions work btw).

Comment: divs and spans with no inner content will still act as "blocks". I added in a red google link for example. updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YWnzc/133/ - Note: the map (z-index of 1), red google anchor tag (z-index of 2), direction anchor tags (z-index of 3). I also stripped away all content anchor tags to show that inner content has no effect, only z-index matters. if you try to click on red google link it wont work. This is why I think the mouse position method will be the best bet. i did some searching around and found this: http://scripterlative.com/files/cursordivscroll.htm

Comment: The above example is javascript though, not jquery

Answer (score 0):

The anchor tags link to themselves so that the browser tries to scroll the tag to the top of the frame when you click them. You can use script to prevent this default behaviour, or change the target of the links.

Comment: I went ahead and updated the fiddle to use "javascript void" in the achor tags... but I realized that using achor tags might be the wrong way to go about this. Read my edit on the post.